# Dynamically update QSqlTableView if the database is changed

Tags: c++, mysql, qt

Here is my code :

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
   db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL");
   db.setHostName("localhost");
   db.setDatabaseName("carl");
   db.setUserName("root");
   db.setPassword("123456ca");


   tmb = new Manifest(this);
   tmb->setTable("carl_table");
   tmb->select();

   ui->treeView->setModel(tmb);



}
```

My application has a single `QTableView` with a `Manifest` as a model.
`Manifest` is my custom `QSqlTableModel` class. Reason for it is because I plan on disabling some columns by overriding flags and it works as intended.

My `SQL database` has two columns, namely the `id` which will be the primary key and `name` which is any string. `Manifest` will be set to that table and it will fetch all the data inside.

Now my problem is that, how do I make my application dynamic? Meaning, if my database table is changed, then I want my application to update itself.

This is the approach that I have thought of:
Make a thread that will run `tmb->select();` in a fixed time. But the problem that I see is that it will mess up my current UI index selections so it will only be editable for a few seconds.

If this is a good approach, then how do I make it work?
Any other methods or solutions will also be greatly appreciated.

I checked and researched SO and found a similar case as mine, but I somehow don't get the explanation.

**edit:** I am thinking of getting the primary key, store it, then re-select it again after refreshing. The thing that concerns me is the performance, since I will have to re-iterate to find the matching PK. Plus, it will be run per second. I am trying to implement this at the moment.

**edit #2:**

I was successful on implementing my own version but i am not sure if this is optimized. My process goes like this :

1. `select` will be run every 1 seconds.
2. before the actual line of `select()`, the clicked `index` will be recorded.
3. after calling `select()`, the index will be restored.
4. scrolling will temporarily stop the timer and it will be resumed if the user clicks on anything.
5. the time will also be temporarily stopped if the user double clicked any attributes.